# Transfer Custom object array from one activity to another

Tags: java, android

I created a class called `CardView`.
`CardView` `object` has 1 property: `int number`

I want to trasfer arrayList of `CardView` `Objects` from `MainActivity` to `MainActivity2`
I tried to do it but when I printed `getNumber` of the first(or any) `object` it `returns` 0 instead of the number I set in new Cardview(int number).

here is the code:

`MainActivity onCreate()`:

```
List<CardView> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new CardView(10));
    list.add(new CardView(11));
    list.add(new CardView(12));
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    mIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) list);
    startActivity(mIntent);
```

`MainActivity2 onCreate()`:

```
List list;
    list = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("Data");
    Toast.makeText(this, ((CardView)list.get(0)).getNumber()+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

CardView Class:

```
public class CardView implements Parcelable {
    int number;
    public CardView(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    protected CardView(Parcel in) {
    }

    public static final Creator<CardView> CREATOR = new Creator<CardView>() {
        @Override
        public CardView createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CardView(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CardView[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CardView[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protected CardView(Parcel in) {
    number = in.readInt();
}

@Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {    
    parcel.writeInt(number); 
}
```

By default the value of uninitialized `int` variable will be `0`, so initial value of `number` is 0. With this constructor `number` receive from parcel.

Comment: Because of this line the app crash onCreate() of the second Activity

Comment: @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeInt(number);
    }

Comment: I already understood it but really, Thank you! Please edit your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBbsvqSu0is&ab_channel=CodinginFlow

I should add the following code to `CardView` class.

```
protected CardView(Parcel in) {
    number = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeInt(number);
}
```